# Magento 2 checkout session

Tags: magento2, checkout, session

Is there any way to store checkout custom field data to checkout session? If possible how can I retrieve data?

Created an event

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="checkout_onepage_observer" instance="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Observer\TestObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer code**-

```
 <?php
    namespace Oye\Deliverydate\Model\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    /**
     * Class SaveDeliveryDateToOrderObserver
     * @package Oye\Deliverydate\Model\Observer
     */
    class SaveDeliveryDateToOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
         */
        protected $_objectManager;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
         */
        public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager)
        {
            $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        }

        /**
         * @param EventObserver $observer
         * @return $this
         */
        public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
        {
            $order = $observer->getOrder();
            $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
            $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
            $order->setDeliveryDate( $quote->getDeliveryDate() );
            //echo $quote->getDeliveryDate();
           // exit();

        }

    }
```

In the observer last line I tried to echo deliverydate custom field value
using `echo $quote->getDeliveryDate();` but not getting that value. Can I use session to store these custom checkout field value?

Comment: give more details at which location (model/controller/block) you are and what you try to save in session.

Comment: If you have captche the custom field data at Magento checkout page then  it is too tough to set save the data at session attribute

Comment: Added More Details please check

Comment: `$quote->getDeliveryDate()` will not show anything unless you have saved `Delivery Date` in quote table.

Comment: saved in quote table also

Comment: I used the event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Comment: can you share what you get if you dump `$quote` like this in your observer `var_dump($quote->getData());` ?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getQuoteId() on null in /var/www/html/WC/magento_test/app/code/Oye/Deliverydate/Model/Observer/SaveDeliveryDateToOrderObserver.php:42

Answer (score 2):

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
) {

    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

public function getCheckoutSession() 
{
    return $this->_checkoutSession;
}
```

**You set a value :**

```
$this->getCheckoutSession()->setVarValue('someValueHere');
```

**You get a value :**

```
$this->getCheckoutSession()->getVarValue(); //someValueHere
```

**Then you unset the value :**

```
$this->getCheckoutSession()->unsVarValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

To know about use of checkout session you should check below link -

> http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-set-unset-get-session/

for more specific answer please share the exact event or requirement when you want to use checkout session.

Comment: I added a custom field in magento 2 checkout page and data saved in quote table.How can I store these data in a custom table after checkout success??

Comment: you need to use any event observer in your module after order success like `sales_order_place_after` or `checkout_submit_all_after` and then there you can save value in your custom table.

Comment: for your help check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162635/which-observer-to-use-after-success-order-on-magento-2)