# Magento 2 Programmatically stop decreasing stock qty while placing an order

Tags: magento2, stock

I don't want to decrease stock qty when order is placed. I know this can be done in admin by setting ***decrease stock*** to ***NO***. But I want to change the update stock logic, so I need to know where can I programmatically stop decreasing stock qty in code.

Answer (score 0):

By programmatically, set an `observer to retain the quantity` after placing the order success. Refer this link to use observer [Which observer to use after success order on Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162635/which-observer-to-use-after-success-order-on-magento-2?rq=1)

**Edit**

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Observer/SubtractQuoteInventoryObserver.php
```

Refer this file, It has the functionality to decrease quantity.

Comment: I tried "checkout_submit_all_after".  but I can't see which function does Magento 2 use to decrease the stock qty.

Comment: See my edit @MagentoLearner

Comment: @MagentoLearner Are you able to stop decreasing qty ?
I did in this way - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317849/magento-2-how-to-stop-decreasing-stock-qty-while-placing-an-order-in-magento-2-v
but it is not working

Comment: @VigneshBala I did in this way - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317849/magento-2-how-to-stop-decreasing-stock-qty-while-placing-an-order-in-magento-2-v
but it is not working