# Magento 2: Custom success page

Tags: magento2

I need to show custom magento 2 success page for customers, who choose specific carrier and payment method. My questions is: Can I do override on magento success page that will be applied only when customer chooses carrier x and payment y?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to override page or create custom module for it.

Comment: create event checkout_submit_all_after and put your login here. for reference : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162635/which-observer-to-use-after-success-order-on-magento-2

Comment: Apply this condition in your phtm file:: if ($order->getShippingMethod() && $payment->getMethod):

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get the order information on the success page. So, you can get your specific carrier and payment method. Depending on that you can easily display custom information conditionally to your customers.

To override that order success page you must edit the following path 
app/design/frontend/vendorname/yourtheme/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Modify the below file in your module
app/code/Vendor/Module/View/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Thankyou" name="order.details.success" template="Vendor_Module::order/success.phtml" after="-">           
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.success" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Thankyou.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Thankyou extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
{
    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $_orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $data);
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return  $this->_order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId(
            $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId());
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    }
}
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/View/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml

```
<?php 
$order = $block->getOrder();
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$order->getShippingMethod();
if ($order->getShippingMethod() && $payment->getMethod):
?>
<div class="checkout-success">
<?php if($order->getIncrementId()):?>
    <?php if ($block->getCustomerId()) :?>
        <p><?php echo __('Your order number is: '.$order->getIncrementId().')' ?>
        </p>
        <?php  else :?>
            <p><?php echo __('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.',$order->getIncrementId()) ?></p>
        <?php endif;?>
        <p><?php echo __('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.') ?></p>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```